# Python: get count of days between dates from two columns in DataFrame without using apply()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'a': date(2020, 2, 1), 'b': date(2020, 4, 2)}])
df['c'] = df['b']-df['a']
# df:
#             a           b       c
# 0  2020-02-01  2020-04-02 62 days
```

the column `c` is counting the days between dates of `a` and `b`. However, its dtype is `timedelta64[ns]`, not an `int` count of days. So I have to do:

```
df['c'] = (df['b']-df['a']).apply(lambda x: x.days)
```

This works. But I am just wondering if there is a more vectorized solution to perform better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `apply`:

```
df['c'] = (df['b'] - df['a']).dt.days
```